# Use of motion constraints for robot's movement simulation

Tags: animation, constraints

I am new to Blender with very basic knowledge. I am working on some robotic simulation for which I already have models, for environment and the robotic unit. The robotic unit has to be mounted on metallic frame, over which the robotic unit has to slide. As shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6wGqDKVxy0) video.

Can someone bluntly guide me through the steps for achieving such a simulation. Especially on the use motion constraints. I am aware of the various constraints Blender provides but not sure which one could give me the similar kind of movement of the robot on the frame, as in the video. Please help me out. Thanks !!

Comment: I have not tried myself yet, except reading out manuals and watching some tutorials videos. This is the first ever time I am dealing with Blender. I want to know which Blender constraint could result in "object sliding on the metal frame" motion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a simple case like the example you can use **Limit_location** constraint on one axis , but for more general case you can use the **follow path constraint**

[image]

to get the previous configuration :

- add ***follow path*** constraint with the following settings then click ***animate path***

[image]

- to take coontrol of the robot position you have to check ***Fixed position***  and use the ***Offset*** slider to animate it.
- for precise movement, the curve used for constraint is the same one used for creating the frame
- the frame is created with ***Array*** modifier and ***curve*** modifier as follows :

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly I wanted to achieve. Thanks a ton !!

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your detailed explanation, I appreciate. I am wondering if you have any experience with morse robotic simulation ?

Comment: @sosoup actually this is the first time and it looks interesting ! are you working on a project with MORSE ?

Comment: Yes I am working with Morse. I have the model of the frame and robot. But I am not sure if Morse obeys the physics related to the "constraints" defined in Blender. Meaning, if robot slides on the frame in the Blender, how to make it work in Morse. I am controlling robot movement using Python. If you have any guidance for me, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: from what i saw MORSE uses the blender game engine which does not respect these constraints , it has it's own constraints + physics constraints ,see the logic bricks to know if it has what you are looking for ,BTW i didn't tried the MORSE so it may be different from the standard BGE

Comment: Ohh that sounds like a bad news. The Morse logic bricks have very few constraints entity, like the actuator constraints for orientation, distance or location. And these constraints does not seem to give me desired result. But somehow I need to find a workaround. Thank you so very much for your continuous support.

Comment: there are other options 'mesh navigation' ,  to get more familiar with the BGE [take a look at this post on BA](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?240729-Prof-Monster-s-Hints-Guides-and-Good-To-Knows), and whenever you face a specific problem ask again on this site, good luck to you :)